# Could not determine if Azure DevOps belongs to a Azure subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am an owner of an Azure DevOps Organization - e.g. "lab.visualstudio.com". We are planning to decommission our Azure subscription. I try to find out if the decommission will affect my Azure DevOps Org.

I can see "lab.visualstudio.com" is connecting to my Azure subscription for billing purposes. However, I could not find "lab.visualstudio.com" in my Azure portal.

Is there a way to determine if "lab.visualstudio.com" belongs to one Azure subscription? In other words, how can I know if decommissioning my Azure subscription will also decommission my Azure DevOps Organization?

Thanks in advance!

---

Notes: I saw someone's Azure portal has their Azure DevOps Organisation on it (screenshot attached). I am wondering why mine does not show in my Azure portal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to determine if "lab.visualstudio.com" belongs to one
> Azure subscription?

To find the Azure Subscription associated with your Azure DevOps organization, login into Azure DevOps, go to `Organization Settings` and then `Billing`. You will see the Azure Subscription used for billing of Azure DevOps organization.

[image]

You can then go to Azure Portal and navigate to the subscription and look under resources. You should see a resource by the name `lab` (or the name of your Azure DevOps Organization) of type `Azure DevOps organization` there.

> In other words, how can I know if decommissioning my Azure
> subscription will also decommission my Azure DevOps Organization?

Azure DevOps uses an Azure Subscription for billing purposes. If you delete the Azure Subscription that is associated with your Azure DevOps organization, your Azure DevOps organization will be immediately moved to "Free Tier". Though I have not tried it but I believe that the resources you have created in your Azure DevOps organization will not be deleted. I'm not sure what would happen if you have provisioned resources more than allowed in free tier.

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/billing-faq?view=azure-devops#what-happens-if-i-delete-my-organization-resource--.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still cannot find my DevOps Organization in "All Resources" in the Azure portal. However, I am able to find it in Cost Management in the Azure portal, which indicates to me that they are not tightly coupled. I think I am safe to continue my implementation. But would be good to find out how to show all associated DevOps Organization in the Azure portal.

Comment: I just tried it and yes, you are correct. I was not able to find the resource group in which `Azure DevOps organization` kind of resources are there. Can you try the method I described in my answer. Basically find the Azure Subscription id from Azure DevOps and then go to that Azure Subscription in Azure Portal. When you go to "All Resources" in that Subscription, you should be able to see your Azure DevOps organization. HTH.

Comment: I tried - still cannot see my Azure DevOps Organization in "All resources", but I can find it in the cost management under this Azure subscription. Not sure if that's because I inherited this Org from someone. I will create a new DevOps Org and connect it to Azure and let you know if that's the case.